# storing the response using useEffect to avoid re-rendering using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using React hooks and trying to figure out, how should I store the response of the api call  `response.data._embedded.assets` in a state variable.

Using `setAssets(response.data._embedded.assets);` doesn't work because of re-rendering. So I decided to use `useEffect` as shown in the code below but this violates the rules of react
hooks -Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. I understand that `useEffect` should be defined outside as per react hooks but then how would I store the response in a state variable ? Please advise.

```
const [selectedTabIndex, setselectedTabIndex] = useState(0);
    const [assets,setAssets] = useState([]);

  
    
    let companyCategory;
    axios
    .get(url, {
        params: {
            assetCategoryId: selectedTabIndex
        }
    }).then(response => {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('companyCategory') !== null) {
        companyCategory = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('companyCategory') )
      
    }
    console.log("Inside response of web api call");
    console.log(response.data._embedded.assets);
    useEffect(() => {
        // Should not ever set state during rendering, so do this in useEffect instead.
        setAssets(response.data._embedded.assets);
      }, []);
    //setAssets(response.data._embedded.assets);
   
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

In a class component, the above state variable declaration would be like this inside the response:

```
this.setState({
        companyCategory: companyCategory,
         assets: response.data._embedded.assets
     })
```

Comment: You say `Using setAssets(response.data._embedded.assets); doesn't work because of re-rendering` but that doesn't make sense. Shouldn't you WANT to re-render, after receiving a response, because that's when you have actual data to display?

Comment: Ah I see now. I think what you want to do is put your Axios call inside a `useEffect(() => {}, [])` (a `useEffect` without any dependencies listed in the `[]` is equivalent to `componentDidMount`) and call `setAssets` from that. The reason you get the too many re-renders is because your API call is re-done every re-render, which then updates state, which re-renders component, which triggers the api call, etc

Comment: When I used `setAssets(response.data._embedded.assets);` there was some sort of loop I can see in console log which was never ending. What might be causing this?

Comment: Check my previous comment :)

Comment: Ok, you mean something similar to what `Kevin C. Ferron` mentioned as his answer below?

Comment: Yes, his answer shows correct implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the whole get request in useEffect.

```
    const [selectedTabIndex, setselectedTabIndex] = useState(0);
    const [assets,setAssets] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Should not ever set state during rendering, so do this in useEffect instead.
        
    
    let companyCategory;
    axios
    .get(url, {
        params: {
            assetCategoryId: selectedTabIndex
        }
    }).then(response => {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('companyCategory') !== null) {
        companyCategory = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('companyCategory') )
      
    }
    console.log("Inside response of web api call");
    console.log(response.data._embedded.assets);
    
    setAssets(response.data._embedded.assets);
   
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
 
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

If a component doesn't need to render when it changes, don't put it in state. You can have a module-scope variable  in your component and use that.

With class components, you can also put it on `this`

Answer (score 0):

why do you fetch data if you don't want to use that,
also we can't use react hooks inside functions

- Call Hooks from React function components
- Call Hooks from custom Hooks